# How can I see all the contents of a variable while debugging?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I do parsing JSON

```
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl();
        json.toString();
```

in debugging "json.toString()", I cannot see the whole entire row, because the line is too long

it turns out that something similar to this

```
"{"VehiclePartItems":[],"BrandItems":[],"TabletSurveyTasksItems":[{"Brand":"Infiniti","ShippingAgentNativeName":"ÐÐÐ¢Ð-13061","Model":"FX37","SecondDriverShortNativeName":null,"ShippingAgentUnitId":"3700bc0b-17cc-47c9-8bca-cd78a258a592","FirstDriverEnglishName":"Saranchuk Viktor Vasyliovych","Vin":"JN1TCNS51U0442875","FirstDriverShortNativeName":"Ð¡Ð°ÑÐ°Ð½ÑÑÐº Ð. Ð.","SecondDriverNativeName":"  ","SurveyPointNativeName":"Ð¢ÐµÑÐ¼ÑÐ½Ð°Ð» ÐÐ²ÑÐ¾Ð»Ð¾Ð³ÑÑÑÐ¸ÐºÐ°","RowState":2,"TruckPlateNumber":"AA1939HE","FirstDriverNativeName":"Ð¡Ð°ÑÐ°Ð½ÑÑÐº ÐÑÐºÑÐ¾Ñ ÐÐ°ÑÐ¸Ð»ÑÐ¾Ð²Ð¸Ñ","ReportNumber":"2011\/640758","CarrierNativeName":"ÐÐÐ¢Ð-13061","RowVer":[0,0,0,0,1,160,127,245],"SurveyPointUnitId":"62e12548-0a68-4999-960b-a3bb3c44675c","SecondDriverShortEnglishName":null,"ShippingAgentEnglishName":"KATP-13061 PJSC","SecondDriverEnglishName":"  ","CarrierEnglishName":"KATP-13061 PJSC","TrailerPlateNumber":"AA9774XP","CarrierUnitId":"3700bc0b-17cc-47c9-8bca-cd78a258a592","Id":"3341661f-8a70-4a8f-b7b0-..."
```

**How can I see all the content?**

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Show output in android logcat.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the text area during the debugging in `Eclipse` and select `Max length...` (`Wrap text` might help as well).

[image]

Comment: Let me just say that Eclipse gets really slow when you output very long lines. I have output lines with more than 30k characters successfully.

Another possibility is to format the code for debugging with something like `.replace("\",", "\"\n,")`

Comment: @Zagrev Never tried such long lines, but probably that is why this is configurable.

Comment: Doh! I haven't looked at that in a long time. Look! Wrap Text. That would do it too...

Answer (score 0):

Most of the IDE use `.toString()` method for variables at debugging. 
With Eclipse start the Debug tool (a green bug icon near the run icon) and place a breakpoint at `json.toString();` Then mouse howler to `json` variable above code line.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

use the variable tab provided by eclipse.
this tab is visible in debug perspective.
if you cant see it then goto windows-show view-variables

check out [here](http://www.comscigate.com/debug/learn_Debug.htm)